# Gravar resposta de API com Angular/Ionic

Tags: angular, ionic, api

Estou com uma dúvida com o Angular/Ionic que estou utilizando para montar um app.

Eu possuo o seguinte provider:

```
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class UsersProvider {
    private API_URL = 'http://localhost:8080/v1';

    constructor(public http: HttpClient) {
    }

    apiHeaders() {
        const headers = new HttpHeaders();

        headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        headers.set('Accept', 'application/json');

        return headers;
    }

    loginUserAccount(email: string, password: string) {
        let headers = this.apiHeaders();

        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            this.http.get(this.API_URL + '/auth/login?email=' + email + '&password=' + password, { headers }).subscribe((result: any) => {
                resolve(result)
            },
            (error) => {
                reject(error.error)
            })
        });
    }
```

E a resposta da função loginUserAccount() eu recebo um JSON "auth-jwt" que ele é o Token do usuário que contém as informações do usuário logado e permite acessar as demais páginas do app.

A minha dúvida é que como eu posso setar meu header "X-Token" com a resposta que vem da API? Buscando no Google e no próprio StackOverflow li sobre a Ionic Storage para salvar dados e recuperar quando bem entender mas não entendi muito bem como ela funciona e como seria a implementação, tem alguma outra forma de salvar o token ou salvar com Ionic Storage é o mais correto? Se a Ionic Storage é melhor como posso gravar o "auth-jwt" nela?

Comment: Pelo menos nos projetos que eu peguei com JWT e ionic colocava o token no Ionic Storage e deixava ele gravado lá depois quando o fosse necessário usar ele eu só pegava do Storage e mandava no header do request, e quando o token expirava eu fazia um refresh nele salvando o novo no Storage.

Comment: Foi isso que eu li e mais comentaram para utilizar mas não achei nenhum exemplo de como utilizar, tem algum exemplo ou como devo adaptar o meu código para utilizar a Ionic Storage e consumir depois?

Comment: Então não é muito recomendado fazer login via GET use um POST, depois eu faria o seguinte no seu provider eu só chamaria o request e trataria o retorno dele no seu controller. Depois de fazer isso pegaria o  retorno dele com o token e gravaria no storage, seu token vai ficar gravado na memória do app ai é só você usar ele quando precisar nas suas requests que necessitam de login